# Google login callback via POST instead of GET

Tags: socialauth

I am currently using a library (**SocialAuth.NET** - http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/) to handle login on multiple social platform.

So far, with facebook and twitter, I had no issues whatsoever. While trying to implement the Google sign-on process, however, sometimes (apparently randomly) an error occurs.

After doing some investigation (debugging the library and using Fiddler and whatever), I came to the conclusion that, sometimes, the login process on the google part comes back to my authentication handler via **POST**, and not via **GET**.
Using Fiddler, I was able to clearly identify all parameters inside the message body (in case of the **POST** callback) or the querystring (in case of the **GET** callback), so google logged my user correctly.

This causes an exception on the SocialAuth.NET library method, since it expects all the parameters to be passed in querystring, and as such the login process fails (on my side, obviously - google considers me logged in since on its side everything went o.k.)

In conclusion, what I'm asking is: why does sometimes google answers my server via a **POST** instead of a **GET**? Is there something I should do to avoid that or it will require a change inside the **SocialAuth.NET** library?

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't faced this issue with Google. It always returns information in querystring. Great if you can somehow identify exact steps of replication. Anyways, if you you want to modify library to check for POST then you'd need to alter ProcessRequest method of Core/callbackHandler.cs (likely line 76).